ffmpeg ignoring framerate settings when trancsoding mp4 to mxf
I'm using ffmpeg to transcode an mp4 file to an mxf file for proxies.
The main problem: ffmpeg ignores my framerate settings and always encodes the output video at 59.9 fps instead of the requested 58.
In this case, the input video has an FPS of 58 (actually an avg framerate of 57442500/996461 as reported by an ffmpeg probe), and I require the output to match, but ffmpeg overrides me and sets it to 59.9.
No matter what I try, I cannot get ffmpeg to write the output file at 58 fps. I've tried the -r and -framerate arguments and I've tried the fps=58 option with vf. I've also tried setting  -vsync cfr, but no luck. I've also tried using the average framerate from the probe (57442500/996461), but again, no change. I've also tried specifying the framerate in the input to match that reported by the probe (no luck).
Here's my code in ffmpeg-python.
in_video = 'video.mp4'
out_video = 'video.mxf'

(
    ffmpeg
    .input(
        in_video,
    )
    .output(
        out_video,
        r=58,
    )
    .global_args('-report')
    .run()
)

And here is the raw command, which I've tried manually entering as well.
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -r 58 "video.mxf" -report

Despite my output settings, the resulting video has an output framerate of 60000/10001 instead of 58/1 or 57442500/996461.
Is there something obious I'm missing? Does the mxf format require certain framerates?
The source video was recorded with my phone, a Google Pixel 6a, if that matters.  The r_frame_rate reported by the probe is 60000/1001 while the avg_frame_rate is the aforementioned 57442500/996461, which is what my editor reports as well.
Alternatively, I'm open to other proxy format suggestions. Though I'll say that .mxf files seem to be the best trade in file size and editing latency I've seen so far. Unfortunately, DaVinci Resolve, my editor, requires the proxy to have the same framerate as the source.
Edit to add report for Gyan
Source code
from pathlib import Path
import ffmpeg

src = Path(
    r"K:\StackO\vid.mp4"
)
dest = src.with_suffix('.mxf')


(
    ffmpeg
    .input(
        str(src),
    )
    .output(
        str(dest),
        r=58,
    )
    .global_args('-report')
    .run()
)

Report on pastebin. It was too large to post on SO, and even too large for pasetbin, so I omitted the middle ~8,000 lines starting at line 884. Hopefully I only removed superfluous stuff.

Share the report.

@Gyan, I edited the question to include the report at the bottom. Sorry for the delay.

The default video encoder for MXF is mpeg2video which does not support arbitrary framerates. Run ffmpeg -v 0 -h encoder=mpeg2video to see a list of supported rates (near the top of the printout).
